Find the size of the radius of the circle.
In the figure. if: $AB = 12m$; $AC = 4m$ and $HE = 8m$.
Calculate the size of the radius of the circle.(Answer:$R=8$)

I try:
$\triangle ABD: BE^2 =AE.ED =(R+OE).(R-OE) = R^2-OE^2$\
$\triangle ABD: BE.2R = 12.BD$
$\triangle ABD: BD^2 = 144-(2R)^2$
$\triangle AHC:AH^2 = 16-CH $
$\triangle ABE: BE^2 = 144-(R+OE)^2$ = 144-(8+AH)^2\
$\triangle ACD: 2R.CH = 4.CD$

This is a PSQ right?

I have a hard time with geometry, so I stick to coordinates, with $A=(-r,0), B=(x_b,y_b)$ and $C=(x_c,y_c).$ Then you get equations $$x_b^2+y_b^2=x_c^2+y_c^2=r^2\(x_b+r)^2+y_b^2=12^2\(x_c+r)^2+y_c^2=4^2\x_b-x_c=8.$$ Then solve for $r.$

Let $AH=x$, and $r$ be the radius of the circle. Extend $CH$ and $BE$ to intersect the circle at $M$ and $N$ respectively.

Note that, $HM= HC$ and $BE= NE$. Using Pythagorean theorem, we have $HC=\sqrt{16-x^2}$.
Now by the Power of a Point Theorem we have $$HC.HM=AH.HD\Rightarrow x(2r-x)=16-x^2\Rightarrow\quad x=\frac8r$$
By Pythagorean theorem in $\triangle ABE$, we have $BE=\sqrt{144-(x+8)^2}$. Similarly, Power of a Point Theorem leads to,
$$AE.DE=BE.NE\Rightarrow (x+8)\left(2r-(x+8)\right)=144-(x+8)^2\Rightarrow r(x+8)=72$$
Substituting $x=\dfrac 8r$ result in, $r(\dfrac 8r+8)=72$. Hence, $r=8$.
